# Can I personalize the placement of nodes (vertex) in a network?

Tags: r, igraph

I'm currently conducting some social network analysis using the `igraph' package in R, and I wanted to know if there is a way to personalize the placement of nodes in the social network.

For example, with the following toy code:

```
    library(igraph)
    edge <- cbind(c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4),c(2,3,4,3,4,1,2,4,2),c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
    vertex <- c(1,2,3,4)
    g <- graph.data.frame(edge, directed=FALSE, vertices=vertex)
    plot(g)
```

In this case, the network is kind of small compared to the plot space. Is there a way I can increase the distance between nodes? And, additionally, is it possible to position a node in a specific place (e.g. (x,y))?

Thank you!

Comment: I tend to remove margin space with igraph.. ie `par(mar=rep(0,4), oma=rep(0,4)) ; plot(g)`. You can set node positions by passing a matrix off `x`, `y` coordinates to the `layout` argument (so for example, here just using the default layout, `mylay <- layout.auto(g)` the use `plot(g, layout=mylay)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in comment by @user20650 - you can pass a layout to the `plot` function

```
plot(g, layout=mylay)
```

If you want to manipulate the layout, the best way is to generate some first:

```
mylay <- layout.auto(g)
```

then if you print `mylay`, you will see it is just a list of pairs (usually a two column matrix, to be precise), where numbers in those pairs are coordinates of a node. So if you want to change the position of a node number X, you have to manipulate Xth pair in the layout. You also can generate the whole layout on your own. See this doc for more: http://igraph.org/r/doc/layout_.html